# How to read python file using WSL?

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have an exported file from python 3.7 (python installed in windows 10, under anaconda3), 
I want to read this file using jupyter notebook and python 3.6.9 (python installed via WSL - Windows Subsystem for Linux)
I used:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\Data\CSV_file.csv", sep = ",",header = None,engine = "python")
```

But I got an error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'D:\Data\CSV_file.csv'

I tried (csv,xlsx) formats but I had the same error. 
the paths of two files are (`/home/user_name` for python 3.6.9 and `C:\Users\user_name` for python 3.7).
How can I read this file using jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use Linux file paths because it is acting like the Linux OS. Change `r"D:\Data\CSV_file.csv"` to `r"/mnt/d/Data/CSV_file.csv"` since `/mnt/d` is equivalent of `D:`.

Comment: Thanks but still not working, the same error message

Comment: Are you on WSL and you are typing python 3 <name of script>? What are you talking about using the Jupyter notebook?

Comment: I installed python and jupter via WSL, I want to used jupyter to read the file for future work.

Comment: Sorry, did you use `mnt/c/`? You probably should use `/mnt/d/` cause I noticed your file is saved in the `D:` drive.

Comment: doesn't he needs to mount the drive first ?

Comment: @Wahalez It's obviously already mounted if he's using it already. My laptop also came with two drives C and D but I combined the D drive into my C cause I didn't need two drives.

Comment: @user12055579 yes I has already changed the drive and file format too, but during that I made stupid mistake, I dropped slash. Now it works, Thanks again