# Errno 2 FileNotFoundError. Trying to run a .bat file using Popen and it doesn't see the file

Tags: python, popen, file-not-found

I am running the code using Ubuntu terminal. The batch file I am trying to run is in the same folder as my python script. I tried:

```
subprocess.Popen("mine_eth.bat") 
subprocess.Popen(r"C:\Users\admin\Downloads\gminer_2_45_windows64\mine_eth.bat")
```

but neither worked and both gave the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHOO2.png)
Here you see the errors and the contents of the folder where the file I want to run is. RunningMiner.py is the code file and mine_eth.bat is what I want to run. I also tried using subprocess.run, but the result is the same. I also get the same error in a different chuck of code that uses different commands to copy a file from one folder to another. What am I missing here? Any help appreciated.

Comment: check `os.listdir()` output if it shows the file check the permission if it has executable permission or not

Comment: You are also trying to use Windows styled paths inside WSL, which is invalid. Please [refer to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61046094/how-to-read-python-file-using-wsl).

Comment: I think you need to do `./mine.eth.bat` in the first option and `/mnt/c/Users/admin/Downloads/gminer_2_45_windows64/mine_eth.bat` in the second